# Is this a class, constructor, or method?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble identifying what exactly this is. At this point, I am familiar with what methods, constructors, and class declarations look like. Which is this? Why does it look like a constructor and a method had a baby?

```
public Polygon polygonFrom(Point[] corners) {  
// method body goes here
}
```

Comment: it is a method, constructors do not return anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is a method

why?

In Java, method declarations have five components, in order:

1. Modifiers—such as `public`, `private`, and others you will learn about later.
2. The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or `void` if the method does not return a value.
3. The method name—the rules for field names apply to method names as well, but the convention is a little different.
4. The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, `()`. If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.
5. The method body, enclosed between braces—the method's code, including the declaration of local variables, goes here.

```
public Polygon polygonFrom(Point[] corners) {  
// method body goes here
}
```

Analyze your code snippet :

> **1**. public is modifier
>
> **2**. Polygon is return type
>
> **3**. plygonForm is method name
>
> **4**. (Point[] corners) is the parameter list in parenthesis
>
> **5**. {} is a method body

Comment: Wow. That's one good answer. :)

Comment: I was under the impression that Polygon was a class, not a return type. Or can it be both?

Comment: No it is return type

Comment: Wonderful! That was my confusion, I thought the convention was to capitalize classes, and very often the beginner's tutorial uses very basic sounding class names. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonZwick you are right about the convention but I am not sure why you are mixing two different concepts here?

Comment: In retrospect, it does seem silly, but the way the beginner's tutorial is formatted, it can be easy for a newbie to mistake one thing for another. I could also afford to pay closer attention ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that returns type `Polygon` and has an array of `Point` as its parameter.

You can tell because you have a return type, and a method name, and a list of formal parameters in its declaration. :)

Comment: I was under the impression that Polygon was a class, not a return type. Or can it be both?

Comment: Use this example to understand: Polygon is a return type and can also be a class. Similar to String. String is a class, but it can also be a return type. :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Polygon in this case is a return type that is all.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it has a return type of Polygon identifies itself as a method, the reason why you think it looks like a constructor is because the return statment is missing in the method. The method would fail at compile time.

It should look like this:

```
public Polygon polygonFrom(Point[] corners) {  
// method body goes here
return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure method body includes return statements...

Comment: Not from what the OP has provided. If the return statement is included it would not look like a constructor. Also methods with void don't have return statement.

Comment: "Also methods with void don't have return statement." they don't need to have one, but can - i.e. read data -> `if(someCondition){return;}` -> `methodConsumingYearsOfCPUTime()`